# Need help on CouchDB rewrites for view with multiple arguments

Tags: json, url-rewriting, couchdb, vhosts

The original question is below the double bar.
Here is an update and I am hoping for more help.

Hi,

I am finally actively back working on this.
I had this project out-prioritized repeatedly over the past year.
I apologize for not even commenting on your response, it really is giving me hope.

I have a cleaner approach and have made some progress I believe.
I now have around 1900 documents in a database.
Each document has a "type" key.
I've made 30 design documents, one per "type", that each have a view called "all" that returns all rows of the document of that type.

So, now I can execute from a browser a GET like this:

dasvm01.com:5984/registryservice/_design/airplaneidtypes/_view/all

My immediate goal is to shorten this to:

dasvm01.com:5984/registryservice/airplaneidtypes

or

dasvm01.com:5984/registryservice/airplaneidtypes/all

To this end, I added a rewrites function to the airplaneidtypes design doc:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/airplaneidtypes",
  "_rev": "11-c28b41a718017cbcd65f82f4acc611cb",
  "views": {
    "all": {
      "map": "function (doc) 
           {  if(doc.ddoc === 'airplaneidtypes') 
               {    emit(doc._rev,doc);  }
           }"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript",
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "from": "/airplaneidtypes",
      "to": "registryservice/_design/airplaneidtypes/_rewrite",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I think that I need to update the CouchDB daemon:vhosts setting:
I took a crack at it, but I really had no level of confidence and it doesn't seem to work/
In Fauxton, I have:

```
daemons     
auth_cache {couch_auth_cache, start_link, []}
... 
vhosts {dasvm01.com:5984, /registryservice/_design/airplaneidtypes/_rewrite, []}
```

Not sure if this is: 
 - close, 
 - way off, 
 - not the correct place, 
 - just needs quotes...

What can you tell me?
I don't understand the notation in the default value of Fauxton:

```
vhosts

    Virtual hosts manager. Provides dynamic add of vhosts without restart, wildcards support and dynamic routing via pattern matching
        [daemons]
            vhosts={couch_httpd_vhost, start_link, []}
```

================================================================

I am struggling to get (any) rewrites to work. I've looked at a lot of examples both here and on other sites.  I've tried to emulate the solutions but with no success.  Some level of confusion comes into play because I am passing two arguments to my view. But based on the examples that I see here [10.5.11. /db/_design/design-doc/_rewrite/path[1](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/rewrites.html) that shouldn't be a problem.

I have this view:

```
 {"dataProvider": {
  "map": "function(doc) {
    if(doc.dataProvider && doc.status) {
      emit([doc.dataProvider, doc.status], doc); 
      }
    }"
  }
}
```

When I hit this URL, the view works fine:

"//ddpspc28:8080/data_providers/_design/basic/_view/dataProvider?key=["TBC-ACT","unstable"]"

I would like to rewrite this so that the URL looks like this:

"//ddpspc28:8080/data_providers/dataProvider?key=["TBC-ACT","unstable"]"

which currently returns:{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}

In an effort to do this, I created a field named "rewrites" in my design document "_design/basic" for my database "data_providers".  In the value of rewrites I have this:

```
"[ 
  {  "from":"/dataProvider",
     "to": "_view/dataProvider"  
  }
 ]”
```

I have also tried this:

```
“[
  {  "from":"/dataProvider",
     "to": "_design/basic/_view/dataProvider"
  }
]”
```

I have also tried this:

```
“[
  {  "from":"dataProvider",
     "to": "/_design/basic/_view/dataProvider"
  }
]”
```

I suspect that I may also need a "query" component to the rewrite, but I would be happy at this point to just get the rewrite to take "dataProvider" and anything that follows and replace the dataProvider with the fully qualified path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rewrite that's defined in the `_design/basic` document, is accessed at:
`//ddpspc28:8080/data_providers/_design/basic/_rewrite`.

So, both your first and last try should work, but they'll be accessed at:
`//ddpspc28:8080/data_providers/_design/basic/_rewrite/dataProvider`

Rewrites won't be very useful (to reduce URL sizes) unless you combine them with [virtual hosts](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Virtual_Hosts). Combined with virtual hosts can be a nice way to centralize an API.

I typically add a design document with no views (called `api`) that rewrites to the other design documents' views, etc.

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear I am on the right track. I am going to post a follow-up and hope that you can help me further along.